# SOSL query in Batch apex

Tags: apex, batch

Can a SOSL query be used in the Batch apex start method?

I used the below code

```
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        return Database.getQueryLocator([FIND '.com' IN EMAIL FIELDS RETURNING Account (Id,Email__c),B__c(Id,Email_of_B__c)]);
    }
```

received the below error

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature:
>   Database.getQueryLocator(LIST>)

Could you please help me out. I need to mask the emails ids in those objects and hence have gone for batch. There are more objects to be included.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to do this, SOSL does return a List (which does implement the `Iterable` Interface). There may be other ways to do it as well, but you can redefine your Batch Apex start method to return an `Iterable<Object>` instead of a `QueryLocator`.

```
public class TestSOSLBatch implements Database.Batchable<Object> {

    public Iterable<Object> start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        return (Iterable<Object>)[FIND '.com' IN EMAIL FIELDS RETURNING Account (Id,Email__c),B__c(Id,Email_of_B__c)];
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Object> scope) {
        System.debug(JSON.serializePretty(scope));
    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {

    }
}
```

The `Batchable` Interface is [documented here](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_interface_database_batchable.htm#apex_Database_Batchable_start) where it specifies that the `start` method should return a `System.Iterable` object (which the results of a SOSL query is)  or a `Database.QueryLocator` (which the results of a SOSL query is not).

I have tested this code in a DE org and it gives the expected results.

Comment: Thanks @Phil. I tried out your answer and it worked! Also as Keith suggested, it will not work for large number of records because of the limits. As i have nearly 6 objects to implement the same logic, i am planning on using a single generic batchable which can be called for all the 6 objects separately one after the other. Please suggest if there are better solutions

Comment: Sounds reasonable, why don't you inject your SOQL query string in the constructor and then daisy-chain your batch jobs together? You should accept my answer to the question you asked (@KeithC is absolutely right about limits, but my answer does answer your question correctly) and then ask another question IMO.

Answer (score 2):

A major advantage of the [Batchable](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_batch_interface.htm) approach is that providing a (SOQL) based `Database.QueryLocator` is returned from the `start` method, the Batchable can process up to 50 million records.

The [governor limit](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm) on SOSL appears to be 2,000 records.

So while a SOSL-based Batchable may work (nice answer Phil Hawthorn), it is only of use for small numbers of objects. For the query in the question, I suggest instead creating two Batchables, one for `Account` and one for `B__c`, both using  SOQL (with `Email like '%.com'`) and `Database.QueryLocator`. Then when the number of matching rows exceeds 2,000 the code will still work.