# How to update 2 objects from batch apex

Tags: apex

Only one object is updating using this method, how to update more than one object?

```
    public with sharing class Batch_act implements Database.Batchable < sObject > , Database.Stateful {
                private Integer currentBatchChain;
                public boolean bReRun = false;
                public Batch_act() {
                    currentBatchChain = 1;
                }

                public Batch_act(Integer chain) {
                    currentBatchChain = chain;
                }

                public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
                    String qry;

                    if (currentBatchChain == 1) {
                        qry = 'Select Id, Test__c From Obj1 Where name != \'P\'';
                    } else if (currentBatchChain == 2) {
                        qry = 'Select Id, Test__c From Obj2 Where name != \'P\'';
                    } else if (currentBatchChain == 3) {
                        qry = 'Select Id, Test__c From Obj3 Where name != \'P\'';
                    }
                    return Database.getQueryLocator(qry);
                }


                public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List < sObject > scope) {
                    List < obj1 > listToUpdate = new List<obj1>();
                    for( Obj1  o1: (List<obj1>)scope)
                    { 
                        if (o1.Test__c == true){
                            o1.Test__c = false;
                        }else {
                                o1.Test__c = true;
                              }

                        listToUpdate.add(o1);
                        System.debug('List to Update is:###' +listToUpdate);
                    }
                    if(listToUpdate.size() > 0)
                    {
                        update(listToUpdate); 
                    }

                  //Condition for obj2 update
                  //......

                    List < obj1 > listToUpdate = new List<obj1>();
                    for( Obj1  o1: (List<obj1>)scope)
                    { 
                        if (o1.Test__c == true){
                            o1.Test__c = false;
                        }else {
                                o1.Test__c = true;
                              }

                        listToUpdate.add(o1);
                        System.debug('List to Update is:###' +listToUpdate);
                    }
                    if(listToUpdate.size() > 0)
                    {
                        update(listToUpdate); 
                    }

                }



            public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {

                   if (currentBatchChain == 1) {
                System.debug('In First Chain#######');
                Batch_actualizadorPagos mb = new Batch_actualizadorPagos(currentBatchChain + 1);
                Database.executeBatch(mb, 5000);
                 }
                     else if (currentBatchChain == 2) {
                        System.debug('In 2nd Chain#######');
                        Batch_act mb2 = new Batch_act(currentBatchChain + 1);
                        Database.executeBatch(mb2, 5000);   
                }
                else if (currentBatchChain == 3) {
                    System.debug('In 3rd Chain#######');
                    Batch_act mb3 = new Batch_act(currentBatchChain + 1);
                    Database.executeBatch(mb3, 5000);

                }
         }
}
```

Comment: You can use [SOSL](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/53312/sosl-query-in-batch-apex) but it has limit of 2k records. Maybe have a batch which accepts some parameter in constructor, based on which it updates object 1 or two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your execute method in a following way:

```
public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List < sObject > scope) {
    if ( currentBatchChain == 1 )  {
                List < obj1 > listToUpdate = new List<obj1>();
                for( Obj1  o1: (List<obj1>)scope)
                { 
                    if (o1.Test__c == true){
                        o1.Test__c = false;
                    }else {
                            o1.Test__c = true;
                          }

                    listToUpdate.add(o1);
                    System.debug('List to Update is:###' +listToUpdate);
                }
                if(listToUpdate.size() > 0)
                {
                    update(listToUpdate); 
                }
   }
              //Condition for obj2 update
              //......
   if ( currentBatchChain == 2 ) {
                List < obj2 > listToUpdate = new List<obj2>();
                for( Obj2  o1: (List<obj2>)scope)
                { 
                    if (o1.Test__c == true){
                        o1.Test__c = false;
                    }else {
                            o1.Test__c = true;
                          }

                    listToUpdate.add(o1);
                    System.debug('List to Update is:###' +listToUpdate);
                }
                if(listToUpdate.size() > 0)
                {
                    update(listToUpdate); 
                }
   }
            }
```

I hope this is clear